# Prove or disprove the function defined by $f(x) = -x$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Is $ f\colon (\mathbb{R}, \tau)\longrightarrow (R, \tau) $ defined by $ f(x) = -x $ a homeomorphism?

I don't even know where to get started on this.

$\tau$ is the half-open line topology defined by $ \tau = \{ \emptyset\} \cup  \{ (a,\infty) \,|\, a \in \mathbb{R}  \} \cup  \{ \mathbb R \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a homeomorphism, since $(0,+\infty)$ is open, but $f^{-1}\bigl(0,+\infty)\bigr)=(-\infty,0)$ isn't.

Comment: How is $ f^-1((0,\infty)) = (-\infty, 0) $ ? Everything makes sense just not sure I understand how the inverse was obtained.

Comment: $f^{-1}\bigl((0,+\infty)\bigr)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,-x\in(0,+\infty)=(-\infty,0)$.